# Using Screen inside /etc/init

Tags: bash, java, screen, upstart

I am trying to launch a .jar inside a screen session at boot using /etc/init

Here is my script (pretty standard:)

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]
console log
chdir /home/administrator/cisco
setuid administrator
setgid administrator
respawn
respawn limit 20 5
exec /usr/bin/screen -S cisco /usr/bin/java -Xms6G -Xmx12G -XX:PermSize=2G -jar cisco.jar nogui
```

If I remove the screen portion of command (/usr/bin/screen -S cisco) the .jar launches perfectly at boot as expected. There is something wrong with the syntax when using screen.

***It should also be noted that I ran init-checkconf on the file (as seen below) and it passed.***

```
init-checkconf -d /etc/init/cisco.conf
```

Please help. I really need to be able to attach back to these sessions to see the java console.

Thanks,
Atomiklan

Comment: You might find this useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049314/3701431